# C++ vector performance with predefined capacity

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector, performance-testing

There is 2 ways to define std::vector(that i know of):

```
std::vector<int> vectorOne;
```

and

```
std::vector<int> vectorTwo(300);
```

So if i don't define the first and fill it with 300 int's then it has to reallocate memory to store those int's. that would mean it would not for example be address 0x0 through 0x300 but there could be memory allocated inbetween because it has to be reallocated after, but the second vector will already have those addresses reserved for them so there would be no space inbetween.

Does this affect perfomance at all and how could I meassure this?

Comment: How do you measure other performance related things?

Comment: Please read some books and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Comment: Yes, in general, you can expect multiple allocations and copying to affect performance. You should write some benchmarks.

Comment: BTW, there won't be 'holes' in your vector: when backing buffer becomes too small, new one is allocated, all the data is copied and old one is deallocated.

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic so if my vector has 10 spaces and i add 100 elements it will copy my vector to a new 100 space vector and delete the other one??

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer try this: https://ideone.com/8WBhGd
(Note: if you run it on your pc, numbers may vary: when and how much the capacity increases depends on your compiler).

Comment: If you define vector as `std::vector<int> v(10)` it doesn't have 10 spaces: it has 10 elements, with default values. The constructor argument defines *size* and not *capacity*. Adding 100 elements would result in vector with size of 110 and capacity of at least 110 but probably more (implementation specific). However, as you are usually adding elements 1 by 1 there would not be one single allocation. Many vector implementations increase capacity in exponential fashion

Comment: @CompuChip You should not presume what allocation scheme the vector is going to use.  Some implementations double the size, one (MSVC) does 1.5 and most start at size 0 not some fixed size.

Comment: @NathanOliver isn't that exactly what I said?

Comment: @CompuChip No you said that the vector starts of at 12 then goes to 20 then 40..., Most vectors will not follow that allocation strategy So I said you should not just say that is what will happen.  As you can see from [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b29a36379505469a) you can have different behavior.

Comment: @NathanOliver ah you were referring to my first comment. Should have said "for example" there. Cannot fix it anymore so will remove the comment to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::vector` is guaranteed to always store its data in a continuous block of memory. That means that when you add items, it has to try and increase its range of memory in use. If something else is in the memory following the vector, it needs to find a free block of the right size somewhere else in memory and copy all the old data + the new data to it. 
This is a fairly expensive operation in terms of time, so it tries to mitigate by allocating a slightly larger block than what you need. This allows you to add several items before the whole reallocate-and-move-operation takes place.

Vector has two properties: `size` and `capacity`. The former is how many elements it *actually* holds, the latter is how many places are reserved in total. For example, if you have a vector with `size() == 10` and `capacity() == 18`, it means you can add 8 more elements before it needs to reallocate.

How and when the capacity increases exactly, is up to the implementer of your STL version. You can test what happens on your computer with the following test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    using std::cout;
    using std::vector;

    // Create a vector with values 1 .. 10
    vector<int> v(10);
    std::cout << "v has size " << v.size() << " and capacity " << v.capacity() << "\n";

    // Now add 90 values, and print the size and capacity after each insert
    for(int i = 11; i <= 100; ++i)
    {
        v.push_back(i);
        std::cout << "v has size " << v.size() << " and capacity " << v.capacity() 
            << ". Memory range: " << &v.front() << " -- " << &v.back() << "\n"; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I ran it on [IDEOne](https://ideone.com/8WBhGd) and got the following output:

```
v has size 10 and capacity 10
v has size 11 and capacity 20. Memory range: 0x9899a40 -- 0x9899a68
v has size 12 and capacity 20. Memory range: 0x9899a40 -- 0x9899a6c
v has size 13 and capacity 20. Memory range: 0x9899a40 -- 0x9899a70
...
v has size 20 and capacity 20. Memory range: 0x9899a40 -- 0x9899a8c
v has size 21 and capacity 40. Memory range: 0x9899a98 -- 0x9899ae8
...
v has size 40 and capacity 40. Memory range: 0x9899a98 -- 0x9899b34
v has size 41 and capacity 80. Memory range: 0x9899b40 -- 0x9899be0
```

You see the capacity increase and re-allocations happening right there, and you also see that this particular compiler chooses to double the capacity every time you hit the limit.

On some systems the algorithm will be more subtle, growing faster as you insert more items (so if your vector is small, you waste little space, but if it notices you insert a lot of items into it, it allocates more to avoid having to increase the capacity too often).

PS: Note the difference between setting the `size` and the `capacity` of a vector.

```
vector<int> v(10);
```

will create a vector with `capacity` at least 10, and `size() == 10`. If you print the contents of `v`, you will see that it contains

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

*i.e.* 10 integers with their default values. The next element you push into it, may (and likely *will*) cause a re-allocation. On the other hand,

```
vector<int> v();
v.reserve(10);
```

will create an *empty* vector, but with its initial capacity set to 10 rather than the default (probably 1). You can be certain that the first 10 elements you push into it will not cause an allocation (and the one *probably* will but not necessarily, as `reserve` may actually set the capacity to *more* than what you requested).

Comment: so using vectorname.reserve(300) or defining vector<int> vectorname (300) is always quicker then when it has to double data because it always has a continues block of memory?

Comment: Those two statements do different things (note the last part of my answer)! But if you know (or can estimate) the number of items you want to add to the vector beforehand, then yes, it is quicker!

Comment: Ah thank you so you initialize one with "0" and the other is empty with reserved memory, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use reserve() method:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
vec.reserve(300);
assert(vec.size() == 0); // But memory is allocated
```

This solves the problem.

In your example it affects the performance greatly. You can expect, that when you overflow the vector, it doubles the allocated memory. So, if you push_back() into vector N times (and you haven't called "reserve()"), you can expect O(logN) reallocations, each of them causing copying of all values. So the total complexity is expected to be O(N*logN), although it is not specified by C++ standard.

Answer (score 0):

The differences can be dramatic because if data is not adjacent in memory, the data may have to be fetched from main memory which is 200 times slower than a l1 cache fetch.  This will not happen in a vector because data in a vector is required to be adjacent.

see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo

Use std::vector::reserve, when you can to avoid realloc events.  The C++ 'chrono' header has good time utilities, to measure the time difference, in high resolution ticks.